# DriverManager.getConnection() is being very verbose

Tags: java, hadoop

Recently we added SSL to our Hive connection. We did this by adding

`ssl=1;sslTrustStore=C:\\keytabs\\keys.truststore;trustStorePassword=foo`

to the end of your Hive URL. Since then when our code gets to the line

`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);` (where `connectionString` is the Hive connection.)

the console outputs a lot of Hexadecimal along the lines of

```
0000: 16 03 03 00 46 10 00 00   42 41 04 92 F4 F4 D7 D9  ....F...BA......
0010: 55 6C 6F 29 2A 4A 79 25   95 38 93 FB 95 91 A3 A8  Ulo)*Jy%.8......
0020: DE B5 0D DC 7E 86 4E 36   20 A4 91 A2 B3 1B 35 36  ......N6 .....56
0030: 89 CB 1C 36 73 BB 42 E4   68 3C F8 57 EF 15 F6 9B  ...6s.B.h<.W....
0040: 9A 1E 81 D1 E9 A3 EA 1E   0F 0D 82                 ...........
```

and things like `CONNECTION KEYGEN` and lots of references to `SERVER`.

Is there a verbosity setting with `DriverManager.getConnection()` or is there another reason my console is being spammed?

Comment: Seems it is trying to import the certificates..into your trustore..as a trusted certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had `-Djavax.net.debug=all` in my run configuration which caused the above output. More information available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html).